# jfilechooser skips last directory

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

The filepath I get here is  one directory up. I selected a folder inside workspace in the filechooser. But the filepath i got is one directory up. Can someone please help me find problem

Code:

```
      if (evt.getSource() == jButtonOutFileBrowse) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        fc.setDialogTitle("Select Directory to save your output file");
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        //fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);   //disable all file chooser

        int i = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (i == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File f = fc.getCurrentDirectory();
            outFilePath = f.getPath();
            try {
                System.out.println("out filepath:" + outFilePath);
                jTextPaneOutPath.setText(outFilePath);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
out filepath:F:\workspace
```

[image: Screenshot of what i chose]

Comment: You're not getting the selected file -- why?

Comment: e.g., `fc.getSelectedFile();`

Comment: I want the directory to be saved so I thought that would be the required thing to do

Comment: But you're selecting a directory(?)

Comment: `@HovercraftFullOfEels` Thanks! That did work but why did `fc.getCurrentDirectory();` did not work?

Comment: Because the current directory is "one directory up"

Comment: yes i am selecting the directory look at the attached screenshot

Comment: (I know that -- my question mark is due to your not using getSelectedFile)